# Graphics spoilt by intermittent jumps

Tags: java, android

I have written a game app with bitmaps moving around the screen. It employs a separate thread which writes directly to a canvas. On my Samsung Galaxy Y the animations seems smooth throughout the game, however on a "Tabtech m7" tablet the smooth graphics appear to be interrupted by intermittent freezes of about half a second duration, and spaced about three or four seconds apart. Is it possible that it is just a feature of the (cheap) tablet hardware, or is it more likely that it's some aspect of my programming?  And if it's me, how could I go about diagnosing the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look in your log to see if the garbage collector is running approximately when you get the freezes. If so you could perhaps try and find out if its you or the system that is allocation memory in a inappropriate way.
In DDMS you can have a look at the Allocation Tracker, could possibly tell you whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, echoing erbsman. To avoid GC make sure you're not allocating any new objects in your game loop. Also, GC's can be kicked off if you do lot of string conversions (ie, updating score) Like if you do Integer.toString(10) kinda stuff.